# Javascript - element.childNodes does not see an append.newchild

Tags: javascript

given the following:

```
<div ID="parent">
<div ID="child1">Children Stuff</div>
<div ID="child2">More Childish things</div>
</div>
<div ID="orphan">Whhhaa I want a mommy</div>


var p = document.getElementById("parent");
var c = document.getElementById("orphan");
p.appendChild(c);
var ch = p.childNodes;
var ln = p.children;
for(var i=0;i < ln.length; i++) {
    console.log(ch[i]);
}
console.log(ln.length);
```

The console output provides:

```
<div ID="child1">Children Stuff</div>
<div ID="child2">More Childish things</div>
3
```

Here's where I am lost:
I need to obtain information out of each child node (including the new child). Naturally I won't be simply outputting it to a console, I need to perform some logic on other DOM elements that share similar IDs as the children.

Why doesn't the element.childNodes; call pick up on the new child?
Any help is appreciated.

The above is sample air-code so I apologize if the syntax is not 100%, but I'm hoping the point gets accross nonetheless.

Comment: Hint: "Air code" is great, but an [mcve] is better - you'll get a quicker, better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping over `ln.length` but reading `ch`:

```
for(var i=0;i < ln.length; i++) {
    console.log(ch[i]);
}
```

That gets confusing very quickly, as `ln` has a length of 3 and contains the child elements. `ch` has a length of 6 and contains all elements (including 3 text elements with just line feeds).

This is really easy to see if you just add 2 more console logs:

```
console.log('ch',ch);
console.log('ln',ln);
```

As here: https://jsfiddle.net/mqhevnsu/

Comment: facepalm! I can't believe I missed that - thanks for pointing out the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Because you mix childNodes and children. Try using only children:

```js
var p = document.getElementById("parent");
var c = document.getElementById("orphan");
p.appendChild(c);
var ln = p.children;
for(var i=0;i < ln.length; i++) {
    console.log(ln[i]);
}
console.log(ln.length);
```

```html
<div ID="parent">
<div ID="child1">Children Stuff</div>
<div ID="child2">More Childish things</div>
</div>
<div ID="orphan">Whhhaa I want a mommy</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It just works if you fix the typos and become consistent in using `p.children` or `p.childNodes`:

```
var p = document.getElementById("parent");
var c = document.getElementById("orphan");
p.appendChild(c);
var ch = p.children;
for(var i=0;i < ch.length; i++) {
console.log(ch[i]);
}
console.log(ch.length);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6d4tmky4/)